# SUMIFS() with including items instead of excluding items

Tags: excel

I have a set of data where I want to add the pay amount if the employees are in a certain group.

Now, with 8 groups A to H, I can use sumifs to exclude E to H as below:

```
=SUMIFS($Q$3:$Q$119,$M$3:$M$119,"<>e",$M$3:$M$119,"<>f",$M$3:$M$119,"<>g",$M$3:$M$119,"<>h")
```

But is it possible to have a simpler statement that does the opposite ie include A to D?

Tried using {"A","B","C","D"} but that did not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic) is an option:

`=SUM(SUMIFS($Q$3:$Q$119,$M$3:$M$119,{"A","B","C","D"}))`

Comment: Ahh, I was close - needed the sum() outside... Well Done!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of suggestions, for which I cannot claim credit.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A5,{"e","f"},B1:B5))

=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A5,{"e","f"},0))),B1:B5)
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly I can only accept one... but voted for it anyway - just as valid, thanks.

Comment: No problem, and thanks. Just to note on the latter formula you could replace the array with cell references.

Answer (score 2):

You need to SUM the SUMIF formula.

Essentially the {} creates an array. So by using this formula;

```
    =SUMIFS($Q$3:$Q$119,$M$3:$M$119,{"A","B","C","D"})
```

the SUMIF will return only the answer for the 1st criteria ("A").

Therefore, if you SUM the full array you will get the sum of:

SUMIF("A") + SUMIF("B") + SUMIF("C") + SUMIF("D")

So use the below;

```
    =SUM(SUMIFS($Q$3:$Q$119,$M$3:$M$119,{"A","B","C","D"}))
```